# Is quoting a thread post on my blog "personal use"?

Tags: discussion, meta, copyright

Several questions:

1. Does my situation fall under "Personal Use"?

I know the Stack Exchange ToS states that any usage whatsoever must be for personal use. And usually that's a pretty clear term for me. However, here I'm not sure if this falls under that term's meaning. What I want to do is quote a couple posts from a particular thread on Stack Overflow in my professional blog.  I mean, it's may be a professional blog, but only in the sense that I use it to showcase my skills to other people. I don't make any money off it.

2. **Assuming it falls under "Personal Use"**: Would I have to black out the usernames of each thread post?
3. **Assuming it falls under "Personal Use"**: Would I have to black out the timestamps of each thread post?
4. **Assuming it falls under "Personal Use"**: Any other information I should know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of this is a definite yes - read through [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (linked at the bottom of every page) and you'll see that personal use and fair use are both allowed in this context, and remember to always provide attribution and links back to the question/answer in point.

You do not need to black out names or timestamps (it is public, after all) but your attribution does need to be in writing, not just an href.

I have done this in various places, on my own blogs and as comments on other people's blogs etc.

Comment: Would using an <href> tag count as attribution?

Also, would I have to black out the usernames and timestamps?

Comment: Oops, I got the site wrong. I meant to say I wanted to quote two posts from **Stack Overflow**, not Super User. Now reflected in original post above. (By the way, is it *Stack Overflow* or *StackOverflow*?)

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I don't think href is enough - I know the link is there but someone who doesn't understand HTML may not.

Comment: Indeed. *bows* Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

The term "for personal use" in the TOS applies only to the content created by Stack Exchange, Inc.:

> (other than Content posted by Subscriber (“Subscriber Content”))

the actual questions and answers are governed by the [CC-Wiki license,](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) which allows usage for *any* purpose, including commercial, as long as attribution guidelines are observed.

Comment: Oh! So that meant **any** subscriber. I thought it was referring to me, specifically. Okay.

Thank you.